Neither intermediate_image_sizes_advanced or intermediate_image_sizes filter is firing
I got the example straight out  of the docs.  brand new wp install, no plugins, no nuthin.
It doesnt dump and it doesnt die().
functions.php:
function wpdocs_disable_upload_sizes( $sizes, $image_meta ) {

    var_dump($sizes);
    die('now im ded');

    return $sizes;
}   
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'wpdocs_disable_upload_sizes', 10, 2 );


Well, that sucked.  Turns out those filters only run when you upload a media.  So, if you want to see the $sizes, you need to upload something.
